# Initializing char pointer inside method

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I want to pass a char pointer as argument to a function like this:

```
void foo(char* array_of_c_str[], const int size_of_array, char* result_ptr)
{
     // my logic

     result_ptr = a[n];
}
```

And call like this:

```
char* result_pointer = NULL;
foo(array_of_c_strings, 5, result_pointer);
printf("%s", result_pointer); // here result_pointer is always null
```

I want to initialize the pointer to char inside function, when debug everything goes fine, but when leave function's scope this pointer becomes null again, how to keep it initialized even when it leaves function's scope ?

Comment: If you want to change the value of the pointer inside the function, you'll have to pass it the *address* of the pointer. In other words, it should take a `char **`, not `char *`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change a value passed to a function.

Change the `result_ptr` to a `char**`, and then pass the *address of* your destination pointer to the function:

```
// Now a double pointer ---------------------------------------v
void foo(char* array_of_c_str[], const int size_of_array, char** result_ptr)
{
     // my logic

     // Note the addition of the * at the front - we want to modify
     // the char* whose address was passed to us.
     *result_ptr = a[n];
}
```

And call like this:

```
char* result_pointer = NULL;

// Pass the address of your pointer:
//                  -------v
foo(array_of_c_strings, 5, &result_pointer);
printf("%s", result_pointer);
```